Extract kth coefficient of power series in Sympy
Given a series in variables x, y, z, I want to extract the kth term of this series using Sympy.
Say the series is given by exp(y) and k=2, I'd like the output to be 1/2.
The following works fine
from sympy import symbols, series, exp
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
expr = exp(y)
k=2
series = series(expr, y, n=10)
kth_coeff = series.coeff(y, k) 
print(kth_coeff)

But
from sympy import symbols, series, exp
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
expr = -exp(3*x/(z*y))*exp(z*y/x + 1/x)
k=2
series = series(expr, y, n=10)
kth_coeff = series.coeff(y, k) 
print(kth_coeff)

returns -z**2*exp(3*x/(z*y) + 1/x)/(2*x**2), which clearly is not the second coefficient.

You asked for the coefficient of y**2 and that is what you got (as you can confirm if you look at the expression). What were you expecting?

The expression I got contains y. That shouldn't be the case. Or am I missing something completely obvious?

preprocess the expression properly and then select the coefficient. Some exprs are just too complicated for the "solver"

@cards Can you give me some pointers on how the preprocess correctly?

get some coefficientS of exp(3*x/(z*y)) -> exp(3*x/z)**(y**-1) and exp(z*y/x + 1/x) -> exp(z*y/x) * exp(1/x) -> exp(1/x) * exp(z/x)**y. Each expansion should be of degree k, then multiply together and get the coefficient of the last product
